# how to access all index set from JSON data using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I am trying to get my user name and password, which I am getting from my server. I already store in `jsondata` which is `NSMutableArray`. However I am getting only one data via `-objectAtIndex:`. I want to call my all data inside the dictionary. I know I have to use `NSIndexSet` but I don't know the proper way to use it. I'm using a `for` loop. I'm not able to access my value for key to match user credentials. Can anybody suggest anything? Here's my code:

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [jsondata objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([username.text isEqualToString:[dict valueForKey:@"username"]]&&[password.text isEqualToString:[dict valueForKey:@"password"]]) {
        username.text=nil;
        password.text=nil;

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:nil];

    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oooops" message:@"Login Credentials did`t Match" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [error show];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *tusername = nil;
NSString *tpassword = nil;
BOOL isLogin = NO;

//jsondata contains many dictionary, so iterate the loop and find the dictionary that
//contains username and password
for(id temp in jsondata)
{
    //check whether the object is Dictionary or not
    if([temp isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {

            NSDictionary *dict = temp;
            if([[dict allKeys] containsObject:@"username"])
            {
                tusername = [dict valueForKey:@"username"];
            }
            else if([[dict allKeys] containsObject:@"password"])
            {
                tpassword = [dict valueForKey:@"password"];
            }
           //Check the condition here
           if(tusername != nil && tpassword != nil)
           {
          if ([username.text isEqualToString:tusername] && [password.text isEqualToString:tpassword])
           {
                 isLogin = YES;
                 username.text=nil;
                 password.text=nil;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:nil];
        break;
           }
          }

     }
}

  if(!isLogin)
  {
        UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oooops" message:@"Login Credentials did`t Match" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [error show];

    }
```

Comment: i don`t have any specific class in my database like temp or any i have oly username password and id and mailed and they are itself directory ..

Comment: temp is not a class. It is a object of type id.The id type is the generic type for all Objective-C objects.I am used it because I don't know what the jsondata contains.

Comment: using this i am getting single value gof user name apart of that i want all value to check whether user name is match or not my json data {"id":"44","username":"moeen","password":"ahmad","emailid":"moeenahmad05@gmail.com"}, like dat many string

Comment: the code itself tell only i store my last value in tusername and tpassword so it ns string value and it store single value of string which is my last username and password in my son dat but i wan`t to check condition from start to bottom for all data in server or in json

Comment: I am modified the code. If condition of username and password inside the loop.

Comment: May I suggest that a setup where a server reports usernames and passwords in clear text to you is criminally unsafe.

Comment: dats really cool even awesome i am missing dat bool value only aprat of dat in ind place of else if we use only if .. else dats great .. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a loop to access all the data on jsondata. Call as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<[jsondata count]; i++)
{
 NSDictionary *dict = [jsondata objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([username.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"username"]]]&&[password.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"password"]]]) {
        username.text=nil;
        password.text=nil;

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:nil];

}

    else {
    UIAlertView *error=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Your alert messege" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [error show];

}
}
```